# how do i redirect a laravel route to a link i create in vue using vue-router

Tags: laravel, vue.js

i am building a single page application in laravel using vuejs. How do i redirect the login to a vue component route. i want to load dashboard component right after login

**this is my login code which which i want to redirect to '/dashboard' i created in vue **

```
public function showLoginForm()
{
    return view('admin.auth.login');
}

public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email'   => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|min:6'
    ]);
    if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt([
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => $request->password
    ], $request->get('remember'))) {
        return redirect()->intended(route('admin.dashboard'));
    }
    return back()->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'));
}
```

**this is the dashboard component route**

```
   export const routes = [

  { 
    path:'/dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent
  },

 ]
```

Comment: So,  the `admin.dashboard` is a Blade template and your SPA starts there with a Vue component, right? If that's the case, then shouldn't your dashboard component just be `/` and not `/dashboard`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a blade called dashboard and redirect to it after login. Then inside this blade you can declare the vue component.

Comment: i have done that by adding "<router-view></router-view>" in my app.blade.php but how do i set a default route for app.blade, so that i will be redirected to '/dashboard'

Answer (score 0):

**i use the '*' for any other path that is not specified**

```
const routes = [
  {
    path:'*',
    redirect:'/dashboard',
    component:DashboardComponent
 }
]
```